# show the linegraph plotted by javafx on an android app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to customize a plot on my Android app. I tried with several available library for Android, however, those libraries can't meet my needs.

I just want to plot from scratch, using `javafx library` to create a customized plot that will be shown on Android app as a view.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to implement this?

Comment: what exactly is your problem with the libraries? what are your 'needs'?

Comment: I am just wondering how I can plot a graph with javafx that will be shown in android app.